# Imported FBX files back to the original size and position

Tags: modeling, import

I have imported some FBX furniture files into my blend file, and I have changed the scale and the position, then I save the file open it again.

The scale and position have been back to the original scale and position as when I imported.

How is this work out?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you saved it? If not don't worry you can recover the file from file>recover>autosave filter it according to the date and select the first one you see.

Comment: Hi Nx, yes, I'm sure. I have tested many times, recover doesn't work because when I recovered it, it would happen again.